# Bottom table row floating to right

Tags: html, css

I am building an email blast using tables. The bottom table row keeps going to the right side of the penultimate row. I can't figure out what the cause is. Can anybody out there lend me a hand? Many thanks in advance!

```html
    <html>
    <head>

    <title>Pup Gear</title>
    
    <style>        

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
    }
    body {
    line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
    }
    table {
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    }

    </style>  
    </head>

    <body>
    <table style="width:600px">
   
     <tr>
        <td><a href="mailto:pup@pupgearcorpotation.com" target=_blank><img 
    src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pup-gear-email-assets/email+top+1.jpg" 
    style="width:600px"</img></a></td>
     </tr>
     
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.doggydocks.com/customer-reviews/" 
    target="_blank"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pup-gear-email-
    assets/email+top+2.jpg" style="width:600px"></img></a></td>
     </tr>
    
  
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://pupgearcorporation.com/Customer-Service/Life-
    Vest-Exchange-Program-and-Sizing-Information" target="_blank"><img 
    src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pup-gear-email-assets/email+bottom+1-
    3.jpg" style="width:600px></img></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td><a href="mailto:sales@pupgearcorporation.com" 
    target="_blank"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pup-gear-email-
    assets/email+bottom+2-3.jpg"></img><td>  
    
    </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Missing a closing `</tr>` tag. Also, img tags are self-closing. You've got an awful lot of typos here.

Comment: I just came here to say wow, that's a lot of classes. Godspeed in your future endeavors

Comment: Also, a quick question on another topic, why do I always get knocked down a reputation point whenever I ask a question?

Comment: TCharb. Yeah I borrowed that code to try and get the email to render correctly in outlook.

Comment: Thank you Tieson T.

Comment: I've added the code snippet in the hopes of seeing what it is you are referring to. If your question is about why there's two images at the very bottom of the page, then that's probably because there is no `style="width: 600px;"` rule for the very last `img` tag. The code is hideous. I would advise rewriting it, so that there is some sort of a format that it follows (the last `td` has so many unclosed tags it isn't funny). Does this do what you want? https://pastebin.com/MDMkLVbq

Comment: I got it to work. Problem was sloppy code. Thx.

Comment: @evilhippy, please post a solution to your problem, outlining the steps, so that other people might benefit from it.

Comment: i cleaned up the various typos, but think it was the missing </tr> on the last table row that was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Error in 4th td.

Close the td correctly as /td.

close the "a" tag before  end of 4th td as /a.

Close the "tr" after the end of 4th /td as /tr.